# Getting a weird error on line 18 about my 2D array (error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscripts)

Tags: c++, console-application

In a separate function, the program takes in user input for the number of rows and columns for a 2D array. I then use a nested loop to get the user to fill in the array with integers. When I run my program I get an error on the line where I get the integers ( cin>>nums[i][j]; ). The error I'm getting is error: invalid types 'int[int]' for array subscripts.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// function to get the user input
void getValues(int &nums, int r, int c)
{
    //get number of rows and columns from user
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>r;
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin>>c;

    // ask use to fillout the array
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter a number for the array: ";
            cin>>nums[i][j]; // ***ERROR IS HERE***
        }
    }
}

// display the 2D array
void display()
{

}

int main()
{
    int r;
    int c;
    int user;
    int nums[r][c];
    
    cout<<"1. Input values"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Display values"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. get sum of all values"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. get row-wise sum of array"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. get column-wise sum of array"<<endl;
    cout<<"6. Transpose array"<<endl;
    cout<<"7. Exit"<<endl;
    cout<<"Chose an option (Enter option number): ";
    cin>>user;

    if(user == 1)
    {
        getValues(nums[r][c], r, c);
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `int &nums` does not look like an array. `int nums[r][c]` is not a valid C++. `r` and `c` are not initialized. `nums[r][c]` is out of array bounds access.

Comment: `int nums[r][c];` -- [This is not valid C++ code](https://godbolt.org/z/7dnfM9obE).  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by compile-time constants, not runtime variables.

Comment: This is also written as if C++ works like a spreadsheet: that is, declare `r` and `c`, declare a 2D array `nums[r][c]`, then, later set `r` and `c` values, and assume that, abracadabra! you have a 2D array that big. C++ is not a spreadsheet. `int nums[r][c];` declares an array, with that size, with the current values of `r` and `c`, which also must be constant, according to the rules of C++, and cannot be changed. The actual compilation error is a cascading error that resulted from making random changes in order to fix one compilation error, but without understanding the error's real reason.

Comment: On top of everyone else's comments, note that your getValues function is expecting an int reference as its first argument ```void getValues(int &nums, int r, int c)```. You should pass a pointer if using an array.
If you want to dynamically allocate your array, you can use std::vector

Comment: `int &nums` is passing a reference to 1 single `int` it's not an array of anything.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass an actual array into the "getValues()" function, you just simply passed an int. Also, passing a pointer to a function(which I am assuming is what you were trying to do) is written as "void foo(int *num)".

```
// function to get the user input
void getValues(int **(nums), int r, int c)
{
    // ask use to fillout the array
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++)
        {
            cout<<"Enter a number for the array: ";
            cin>> nums[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

The process of inputting the rows and columns was moved to the main function as you need them in order to correctly set up your 2D array. I used method 3 in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function) to create the 2D array as this allows the function you are passing it to not define the size of the array it's getting. This also allows it to have the functionality of a pointer, so changing the values in the "getValues()" functions changes what they are in memory.

```
int main()
{
    int r;
    int c;
    int user;
    
    cout<<"1. Input values"<<endl;
    cout<<"2. Display values"<<endl;
    cout<<"3. get sum of all values"<<endl;
    cout<<"4. get row-wise sum of array"<<endl;
    cout<<"5. get column-wise sum of array"<<endl;
    cout<<"6. Transpose array"<<endl;
    cout<<"7. Exit"<<endl;
    cout<<"Chose an option (Enter option number): ";
    cin>>user;
    
    //get number of rows and columns from user
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows: ";
    cin>>r;
    cout<<"Enter the number of columns: ";
    cin>>c;
    
    //Create a 2D array
    int **nums = new int*[c];
    
    //Define all the inner dimensions as int[]'s with the size c
    for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        nums[i] = new int[c];
    }

    if(user == 1)
    {
        getValues(nums, r, c);
    }
    
    cout << "nums[0][0] = " << nums[0][0];
    
    return 0;

}
```